# can someone explain an element in this simple factorial script in JS

Tags: factorial

Yep, this noob is trying to understand a simple factorial function and was confused about one part of it.

In

```
var f = [];
function factorial (num) {
   if (num === 0 || num === 1) {
     return 1; }
  if (f[num] > 0) {
    return f[num];}
  else {
     return f[num] = factorial (num - 1) * num;  
   }
factorial(4);
```

what exactly does the

```
if (num === 0 || num === 1) {
 return 1; }
```

part do and why is it necessary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the base cases of the factorial function. 0! = 1 and 1! = 1, so it returns those values in those cases. If you recurse with no base case, you'll end up recursing indefinitely, yielding no actual value.

Another solution would be to add those cases pre-calculated into `f`:

```
var f = [1, 1];
```

Then it would be caught by the second condition.